# Number of possible guessess - Guess game using binary search

Tags: java, binary-search

I need some help figuring it out how many possible guesses can a person have after proving the first guess given a range such as 7 to 9. In this example, let's say we use 8 as first guess then we only have 2 left guesses. I'm trying to come up with a java game using binary search. Below is the method I'm working on. I'm getting 1 instead of 2 guesses. Can you give me a hand? Trying to learn Java.

```
public static int FindMaxGuesses(int guess, int low, int high) {
    int MAX = 0;

    for (int i = low; i <= high; i++) {
        MAX++;
        int mid = (high + low) / 2;
        if (mid < guess) {
            low = mid + 1;
        } else {
            high = mid - 1;
        }
    }
    return MAX;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think this algorithm will produce the max guesses?

Comment: What does binary search has to do with the length of an interval? Or do you assume that the guesses are given by the binary search algorithm?

Comment: Thanks OldCurmudgeon-

Comment: is it because of the interaction the algorithm does? Sorry I'm new at this! Lol

Comment: @GalAbra... I'm assuming! I'm probably wrong!

Comment: @Dexter the maximum amount of guesses would be to guess every wrong number in the given range, when only the final guess is the correct one. So for interval `[x,y]` the maximum amount of guesses is `y-x`

Comment: @GalAbra - Thanks a lot for your comment. How about this? Does it make sense with what you are saying?                                                               `  int mid = (high + low)/2;
         
         if(mid == guess)
         {
            return MAX = high - low;
         }
         
         
      if(mid < guess)
          {
        low = mid + 1;
               
          }
         else
          {
           high = mid - 1;
            
          }
         
        MAX = high - low;
     }
`

Comment: @GalAbra - I'm sorry I tried to add the code in the comment but I'm helpless. I hope you can read it.

Comment: I think the result you're aiming to is how many searches does a binary search need in order to find a given number in a given range

Comment: Yes, kind of... That is why I was thinking about MAX++ on every search. However, for example a range would be 7 to 9... my first guess would be 8 which would be true but it needs to give me 2 for possible guesses even if I guessed right. The other 2 guesses would be 7 and 9.